# Ruby on Rails: A User has many songs, a song has many feedbacks, display all feedbacks for a user's songs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so forgive the poor skills as well as nomenclature.

I have 3 models.

Users
Songs
Feedbacks

- Users has many Songs and has many Feedbacks.
- Songs belongs to Users and has many Feedbacks.
- And Feedbacks belongs to Users and belongs to Songs.

On the User's profile, I want to show:

- All the songs the user has posted
- All the feedbacks the user has left
  on other user's songs
- and all the feedback the user has received on his own songs

Right now I'm doing this in the controller with something like this:

```
def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @songs = @user.songs.paginate(:page => params[:song_page], :per_page => 5)
    @feedbacksGiven = @user.feedbacks.paginate(:page => params[:feed_page], :per_page => 10)
    @feedbacksReceived = @user.songs.paginate(:page => params[:feed_received_page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

And then in my view, I actually access the feedbacks the user has received by:

```
<% @feedbacksReceived.each do |song| %>
      <% if song.feedbacks.any? %>
      <% @userFeeds = song.feedbacks.all() %>
      <% @userFeeds.each do |feed| %>
      etc.
```

However, this shows each of the feedbacks batched together by song. Where as I want to be able to display all of the feedbacks in descending order based on created_by. This method also messes with the will_paginate method.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

The basic premise of what I want to be able to do is:

```
@feedbacksReceived = @user.tracks.feedbacks
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code from your models as in how you're using `has_many` and `belongs_to`. Specifically for the `User` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `feedbacks`, so you need to ask/query for `feedbacks`, so you need to do it a bit in reverse, like so:

```
@feedbacksReceived = Feedback.joins(:song).where(:songs => { :user_id => @user.id }).order(:created_by => :desc).
  paginate(:page => params[:feed_received_page], :per_page => 10)
```

But there is a simpler way of doing it with associations, just add a `has_many :through` association:

```
# in the user model:
has_many :feedbacks_received, :through => :songs, :source => :feedbacks

# in the controller:
@feedbacksReceived = @user.feedbacks_received.order(:created_by => :desc).
  paginate(:page => params[:feed_received_page], :per_page => 10)
```

NOTE: Not tested, and I too may be incorrectly using `feedbacks` plural form :).

Comment: Yes! This was the simple answer I was looking for (the second solution. It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to learn from this so I'll do my best to cover each of them. First it looks like you're wanting the feedback from a users song, so a good way to do this is `include` that data in your query to `@user.songs`.

```
@songs = @user.songs.includes(:feedbacks).paginate(:page => params[:song_page], :per_page => 5)
```

Then in your view

```
@songs.each do |song|
    song.feedbacks.each do |feedback|
        # Do stuff with that feedback
    end
end
```

The reason to use includes is so that you're not making N+1 queries. You should also avoid doing database queries in your view, it's a bad practice.

The above solution doesn't paginate the feedback which is a separate issue and can be tricky when you're wanting to do this over a collection of objects. Typically you'll paginate a collection of child objects to a single parent. The reason being that if you are on page 2 of feedback does that mean you want to return the 2nd page of feedback for all songs in that collection or just a specific one?

NOTE: I may be incorrectly using `feedbacks` instead of `feedback`. I'm not sure how rails will pluralize `Feedback` which is technically both the singular and plural form of the word.

The last note I'll make is that I would suggest using some jquery or other front end code to hit a js endpoint for each song. That way you can essentially query a single endpoint passing up the song id and the paging parameters for the feedback. It would make the application more robust but is also a much more advanced solution.

Comment: Hey Tyler, thanks for the response. The answer below actually ended up working perfectly. Using "has_many :feedbacks_received, :through => :songs, :source => :feedbacks" in the User model.

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion, but was waiting for you to post your model code. Best of luck on your adventures with Rails.